# Supplementing potassium to get my 4.7g RDA - is it safe?

Tags: micronutrients, supplement, minerals, potassium

Potassium supplements are limited to 100mg, however the RDA is 4.7g. From the foods I do eat (and will continue to do so), I get around 1.5g of potassium per day, which is way too little. However, is there something about potassium supplementation that is unsafe, or why are the supplements limited to 100mg exactly?

Comment: I have seen Potassium Gluconate 500mg from many brands

Comment: @RobertLong I'm not talking about availability though. I know that potassium is prescribed in 500mg or so with certain conditions, but it is prescribed, not over the counter. Though 500mg is still almost 10 times less than the RDA.

Comment: I wasn't talking about availability. Supplements are available OTC in larger doses than 500mg - I just saw one on Amazon that is 865mg and another that is 595mg.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Best-Naturals-Potassium-Gluconate-Supplement

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Potassium-Supplements-Cheers-Highly-Absorbable-Cardiovascular/dp/B078BBW2K7

Comment: @RobertLong Wow, thanks! I'll buy it from my supplier to supplement for 2.5g per day without concerns then. :)

Comment: @RobertLong US law prohibits supplements from containing more than 99 mg of elemental potassium. 500 mg of potassium gluconate contains **less than** 99 mg of elemental potassium. The same situation is true of potassium citrate. Don't be fooled by supplement makers intentionally trying to fool you. Those supplements are a complete waste of money. They provide less potassium than a glass of orange juice.

Comment: @CareyGregory That's a good point also. Or a banana. Though I cannot eat bananas and a glass of organge juice will get your blood glucose sky high, which I am avoiding, so I will stick with high dosage supplements, since they seem to be safe if taken with care.

Comment: @Jack The list of foods higher in potassium than OTC supplements is long, delicious, and cheap. Using potassium supplements is just plain foolish. But it's your money to waste. Feel free.

Comment: @CareyGregory Why do you say it's a waste of money? Supplementing is A LOT cheaper than foods, and unless you're buying organic, it's most certainly healthier as well.

Comment: @CareyGregory Potassium supplements in powder form are OTC. Exceeding the 99 mg dosage limit of a pill is then very easy.

Comment: @Jack It's a waste of money for three reasons. First, the unit price of supplements is **much** higher than the unit price of any food you can name. Second, you have to eat anyway, and foods that contain more potassium than supplements are cheap and common (potatoes, nuts, vegetables, fish, fruit... the list is endless). Third, in order to reach your goal of 4.7 g per day, you're going to need to take 32 pills per day. Do the math.

Comment: @JonathanCender Yes, you can buy it in bulk form. I happen to know quite a bit about that because I spent two years using bulk potassium to deal with a medical issue. Pure potassium chloride is a very good way to kill yourself if you don't know what you're doing. I wonder how Jack's kidney function is, if he has diabetes, or if he's taking any potassium-sparing medications. He'd better know the answers to those questions before heading down this route.

Comment: @CareyGregory Yes. I agree. Jack should know the answer to those questions. I hope someone posts an answer on the safety of potassium as Jack asked for originally. Doctors usually prescribe the citrate form of potassium, yes? Did you use the chloride form?

Comment: @CareyGregory I don't know where you are looking up prices, but where I am, it's A LOT cheaper than any foods. Also, if you know your science, you have to care to not overeat a lot of foods, and I don't know about prices where you are, but where I am, most of the foods that you mentioned costs a lot and isn't even available organic. As Jonathan said, higher dosages are available, so you don't need to go insane with 32 pills. Bulk is exactly what I was talking about, so I don't know why you are writing this.

Comment: @CareyGregory Yes, of course there are concerns, just like with any supplement, a lot of foods, and even salt and water. Thanks for mentioning that, though I already knew about that. I would indeed still like a full non-biased detailed answer to that, as you mentioned.

Comment: @JonathanCender No, prescription potassium supplements are chloride, usually in extended release form.

Comment: @Jack Now you're being absurd. Nowhere in the world is food more expensive than potassium supplements. Just do whatever you want. I'm done with this.

Comment: @CareyGregory Organic food high in potassium*. :) You can confirm that simply by checking prices.

Comment: @CareyGregory My prescription was for citrate. A cursory search shows doctors prefer prescribing citrate for reducing kidney stones for example. I do not know if that had anything to do with my prescription, however.

Comment: @CareyGregory  My error. Correction = My prescription was for the chloride form, not the citrate as I mistakenly said above. I did switch, on a doctor's advice, to citrate powder. I still take some occasionally for symptomatic relief. The powder contains magnesium citrate in addition to potassium as the combo is said to reduce the risks of potassium by itself.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Multivitamin-mineral supplements in the US do not contain more than
**99 mg** of potassium per serving to avoid overdose.

[Linus Pauling Institute](http://lpi.oregonstate.edu/mic/minerals/potassium):

> Oral doses greater than **18 grams** taken at one time in individuals
>   not accustomed to high intakes may lead to **severe hyperkalemia,** even
>   in those with normal kidney function.

In individuals with somewhat impaired kidney function (without them knowing it), the toxic dose can be considerably lower.

**2)** [**Foods**](http://www.nutrientsreview.com/minerals/potassium-kalium.html) that contain **more than 500 mg potassium per serving:** avocado, jackfruit, pomegranate, dates, kiwi, banana, potatoes, beet greens, tamarind, white beans, red salmon. Foods with 300-500 mg potassium: various fruits, legumes, fish and meats.

**3)** Strictly speaking, **4.7 g** potassium/day is not Recommended Dietary Allowance (RDA), but Adequate Intake (AI), which is believed to cover the needs of **all** healthy adults ([Institute of Medicine](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK56068/table/summarytables.t3/?report=objectonly)). The needs for nutrients in general increase with calorie needs. This means that AI 4.7 g potassium/day is what people with the highest needs (athletes, heavy physical workers) who spend more than 4 K Calories/day may need and not necessary what average adults who spend 2-2.5 K Calories/day need.

**4)** Additionally, according to [National Academic Press](https://www.nap.edu/read/10925/chapter/7#230):

> Given the interrelatedness of sodium and potassium, **the requirement
>   for potassium may well depend on the level of dietary sodium**...

So, if you decrease your sodium intake, your potassium needs will be likely lower.

**5)** If studies show that high intake of *foods* high in potassium is associated with health benefits, this does not automatically mean that potassium *supplements* are beneficial. This is because it is not actually known, is it potassium or are other nutrients (calcium, magnesium) in foods high in potassium, or their combination, which is actually beneficial.

[PubMed Central, 2013](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23558164):

> High quality evidence shows that increased potassium intake reduces
>   blood pressure in people with hypertension.

[PubMed Central, 2006](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16856053):

> This systematic review found no statistically significant effect of
>   potassium supplementation on blood pressure.